# How to set the CornerRadius of a UWP TextBox without copying and updating the whole default TextBox style?

Tags: xaml, uwp

I can copy the default style from [there](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299154.aspx) and modify it to set the `CornerRadius` of the borders.

However, I find it heavy. Isn't there a way to just tell my `TextBox` to use a `ControlTemplate` to derive from the default one with "just" a property changed?

Answer (score 0):

This idea is easily understood, say when defining a new `Style`, it can be [based on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.style.basedon#Windows_UI_Xaml_Style_BasedOn) another `Style` with a few properties being overridden. This fits well into the inheritance scenario in OO.

But [ControlTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.controltemplate#properties) has no such thing as "base `ControlTemplate`", because `ControlTemplate` isn't really a set of properties/behaviors that can be overridden, `ControlTemplate` is an integral entity, comprising of different template parts. Putting in OO analogy, it is like a class that doesn't *expose* any virtual method for you to override.

So you have to edit on the entire copy of the original template.

Comment: But how would I derive from the default style anyway as it seems to have no name to refer to?

Comment: When you define a new style derive from the default style, you don’t need to refer to the default style, right? It has all the default values in the default style.